# How to retrieve data from a list in Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, angularfire2

[image: How do I retrieve the schedules in the pic?]

1. When you afDatabase.list(`/schedules/`).push({ meeting} on firebase it adds a record to 'schedules' but it also generates a unique key.  How is that record associated with a particular user?  The below screen shot is 2 schedules created by the same user but has different keys.  How do I associate this unique key with this particular user in order to display the information to the user?
2. Also what if I want to see another user's schedule in the company...how do I associate the schedule in firebase with the other user?

So in summary, how do I read data from Firebase for a particular user given the key is autogenerated by firebase?

I'm using typescript and ionic framework

Comment: You have to manage the `UserId` in firebase database to filter the data.

Answer (score 1):

You have to link user and schedules. For example suppose you have one databaseref(/user). And when adding (/schedules) data first set the user and then push the schedules. In that way each user can have multiple schedules and  schedules can be retrieved using the user.

```
To add:
database.ref(/schedules).child('<username>').push('<schedule_data>');

To get: All schedule of a user
database.ref(/schedules).child('<username>').once('value', function(snap){
console.log(snap.val());
});
```